# Subtract two dates in python when "Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported."

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates in python. You used to be able to do that very simply, by just doing `df['date1'] - df['date2]` (assuming your dates are in datetime). But now when I do that, I get the exception:

```
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
```

The only answered question to this issue is for someone adding a known amount of days to a date. I do not know what the amount of days between these two dates is, hence why I'm trying to calculate it. I don't understand how  'use `n * obj.freq`' is supposed to help me with this use case.

```
id. date1. date2
1. 2022-01-01. 2022-02-01

2. 2021-10-15. 2022-10-17

3. 2022-01-24. 2022-03-24
```

I want to add a column that calculates the difference between these dates and expresses it in days, e.g.,

```
id. date1. date2. delta
1. 2022-01-01. 2022-02-01. 31

2. 2021-10-15. 2022-10-17. 2

3. 2022-01-24. 2022-03-24. 59
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you're using to create the DataFrame and that causes the error?

Comment: "*assuming your dates are in datetime*" - did you make sure this is the case? the dtype you want here is datetime64[ns].

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction should work directly. However, you need `n * obj.freq` for the modulo:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

df['delta'] = df['date2'].sub(df['date1']).mod(365*Day()).dt.days
```

Output:

```
   id      date1      date2  delta
0   1 2022-01-01 2022-02-01     31
1   2 2021-10-15 2022-10-17      2
2   3 2022-01-24 2022-03-24     59
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
 'date1': [Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-15 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-01-24 00:00:00')],
 'date2': [Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-17 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-03-24 00:00:00')]})
```